# Apex trigger not step in isUpdate

Tags: count, trigger-oldmap

In the following apex trigger it does not step in isUpdate. It works properly in case of new insertion or deletion, but in case of update it does not removes the old ID from the list. As per the debug log it does not even step into the isUpdate part. Thanks for checking.
Lilla

```
trigger CountOpenJobs on AVTRRT__Job__c (after insert, after undelete, after delete, after update) {    
    Set<Id> setOpenJobAccountIds = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> setClosedJobAccountIds = new Set<Id>();
    List<Account> listAccountUpdate = new List<Account>();
    List<Account> listOpenJobAccounts = new List<Account>();
    List<Account> listClosedJobAccounts = new List<Account>();
    if(Trigger.IsAfter){
        if(Trigger.IsInsert || Trigger.IsUndelete  || Trigger.isUpdate) {
            for(AVTRRT__Job__c t: Trigger.new) {
                if(String.valueOf(t.AVTRRT__Account_Job__c).startsWithIgnoreCase('001')) {
                    if(t.AVTRRT__Stage__c.equalsIgnoreCase('Open')){
                        setOpenJobAccountIds.add(t.AVTRRT__Account_Job__c);
                        setClosedJobAccountIds.remove(t.AVTRRT__Account_Job__c);
                        System.debug('@@@@Inside Closed@@@'+setOpenJobAccountIds);
                    }
                    else {
                        setClosedJobAccountIds.add(t.AVTRRT__Account_Job__c);
                        setOpenJobAccountIds.remove(t.AVTRRT__Account_Job__c);
                        System.debug('@@@@Inside Open@@@'+setClosedJobAccountIds);
                         }
                    if(Trigger.IsUpdate){
                        if(Trigger.oldMap.get(t.Id).AVTRRT__Account_Job__c != t.AVTRRT__Account_Job__c){
                            if(t.AVTRRT__Stage__c.equalsIgnoreCase('Open')){
                                setOpenJobAccountIds.add(Trigger.oldMap.get(t.Id).AVTRRT__Account_Job__c );
                                System.debug('@@@Inside Update Closed@@@'+setOpenJobAccountIds);
                            }
                            else {
                                setClosedJobAccountIds.add(Trigger.oldMap.get(t.Id).AVTRRT__Account_Job__c );
                                System.debug('@@@Inside Update Open@@@'+setClosedJobAccountIds);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }        
        if(Trigger.IsDelete){
            for(AVTRRT__Job__c t : Trigger.Old){
                if(String.valueOf(t.AVTRRT__Account_Job__c).startsWithIgnoreCase('001')) {
                    if(t.AVTRRT__Stage__c.equalsIgnoreCase('Open')){
                        setOpenJobAccountIds.add(t.AVTRRT__Account_Job__c);
                        System.debug('@@@@Inside Deleted Open');
                    }
                    else {
                        setClosedJobAccountIds.add(t.AVTRRT__Account_Job__c);
                        System.debug('@@@@Inside Deleted Closed');
                    }
                }
            }
        }            
        listOpenJobAccounts =[SELECT Id, Name, Open_Job__c,(Select AVTRRT__Stage__c From AVTRRT__Job1__r Where AVTRRT__Stage__c = 'Open' ) FROM Account WHERE Id =:setOpenJobAccountIds];
        listClosedJobAccounts =[SELECT Id, Name, Closed_Job__c,(Select AVTRRT__Stage__c From AVTRRT__Job1__r  Where AVTRRT__Stage__c != 'Open' )  FROM Account WHERE Id =:setClosedJobAccountIds];
        System.debug('@@@@ListOpenJobAccounts'+listOpenJobAccounts );
        System.debug('@@@@ListClosedJobAccounts'+listClosedJobAccounts );       
        for(Account acc:listOpenJobAccounts) {
            List<AVTRRT__Job__c> listJob = acc.AVTRRT__Job1__r ;
            acc.Open_Job__c = listJob.size();
            listAccountUpdate.add(acc);           
        }
        for(Account acc:listClosedJobAccounts) {
            List<AVTRRT__Job__c> listJob = acc.AVTRRT__Job1__r ;
            acc.Closed_Job__c = listJob.size();
            listAccountUpdate.add(acc);           
        }
        try{
            System.debug('@@@@listAccountUpdate'+listAccountUpdate);
            update listAccountUpdate;
        }catch(System.Exception e){
            System.debug('@@@error'+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your trigger is running on `after update` ops? i.e `trigger customTriggerName on SObject (after update) { ... }`

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Related to @TSmith's comment, it's always a good idea to ensure you include more information in your question than you think is necessary; here, you chopped out the trigger declaration and this is potentially the source of the problem. Obviously we don't want to be overloaded with hundreds of lines of code, so it is always best to remove parts of the code that are definitely unrelated to the problem. Also, if you get any errors, it is always important to include those in the material you provide in the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot @TSmith and @Phil W , I just did not put enter after the `` , so the first line was missing, I have edited it. Thanks again for checking :)